# Swivel two columns QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a column with several data separated by a comma, I wanted to separate them into several columns and to rotate the X column created to have only one

```
N ° | circuit | Cx1 | Cx2
1   | C1, C2  | C1  | C2
2   | C1      | C1  | 
3   | C1      | C1  |
```

Result hope

```
N ° | circuit | CP1 |
1   | C1, C2  | C1  |
1   | C1, C2  | C2  |
2   | C1      | C1  |
3   | C1      | C1  |
```

Comment: Will the input table ever contain additional *Cx_* columns, such as Cx3, Cx4, etc?

Comment: thank you for your answer, no it will have a maximum of 3 data